# Correctly binding multiple knockout viewmodels with Turbolinks?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, turbolinks

Currently, the website I'm working on uses knockout for our frontend framework. I want to incorporate Turbolinks with multiple knockout viewmodels across different pages. The problem I'm running into is that since turbolinks doesn't actually change the page, bindings get applied multiple times which results in an error.

So far here is what I have tried.

I found [this article](https://limecode.dk/2015/09/30/using-knockout-with-turbolinks) which describes exactly what I want to do but doesn't necessarily work.

His solution is to replace the `ko.applyBindings` with

```
window.applyTurboBindings = function(node, viewModelAccessor) {
  return $(document).one("page:change", function() {
    return ko.applyBindings(viewModelAccessor(), node);
  });
};
```

and use it with this

```
applyTurboBindings(document.getElementById('my-node'), function() {
  return new MyViewModel();
});
```

`page:change` is no longer a method used with turbolinks according to their documentation. So I tried it using `turbolinks:load` (which fires once after the initial page load, and again after every Turbolinks visit) and `turbolinks:visit` (fires immediately after a visit starts). That wasn't working either. The event never gets triggered when I call the method `applyTurboBindings` so no bindings get applied.

Here is a fiddle with a basic setup of what I'm doing. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chris_scott718/vdmfo0ak/)

When I run this through my debugger, the `applyTurboBindings` never catches the event (`turbolinks:load`) that is firing.

One idea I had was to use something like this:

```
$(document).one("turbolinks:load", function () {
  // execute all js for page here
});
```

instead of the typical

```
$(function(){
  // execute all js for page here
});
```

But I couldn't get that working either because bindings were still getting applied multiple times.

So my question is how on earth do I get this working for multiple viewmodels so the bindings don't break? Should I be organizing my js differently? Is there a simple solution I'm not seeing or is this just not a good idea use both together?

This is my first question on Stack Overflow by the way so if I'm missing anything or I didn't make my question clear enough please let me know. Thanks for your help.

Comment: With your fiddle the reason it's not getting hit is that the javascript is already placed in a document.ready() function by jsFiddle so the turbolinks:load function has already been hit before the javascript is even executed. If you change the jsFiddle options with the gear in the JS section to LoadType: nowrap-in<head> it will fire.

Comment: @JasonSpake That did it for the fiddle. So should I be calling the applyTurboBindings function in the head of my documents?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on where you load the turbolinks library. You want to set up your event handler first and then load the library because the library automatically starts as soon as it's loaded. (Unless it's loaded with AMD).

Comment: @JasonSpake that makes sense. I'll try loading it with AMD. Thank you!